# teamviewer and windows 7 uac

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, uac

I have to install a software on a remote desktop by teamviewer.
I am authenticated with administrator credentials by teamviewer windows authentication.
The problem is that when I run the setup (I am on limited user environment) it prompt with uac and disconnect the session.
How can I solve the problem ?
I tried with ammyy admin, but kaspersky block the execution of ammyy.

Comment: If you have administrator access to the computer I suggest setting up kaspersky to unblock ammyy.

Comment: I can't access to kaspersky from remote.. for security.. even if I am administrator.

Comment: Have you tried temporarily turning off UAC?

Comment: @Luigi - Have you simply tried the `Remote Desktop` client in order to adjust Kaspersky?  You don't indicate the reason you can't access Kaspersky, having the UAC problem, is easily solved by using a different product that fully supports Windows 7.

Comment: No, simply the kaspersky GUI is totally disabled from remote connection. Any remote connection. The it does not answer to any click from remote and local user can't change anything on kaspersky because he is not admin.